# amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(Message message) returns after 20-40 ms, even after the listener has received it. How to make send() faster?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a sample application using the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I have a rabbit sender which is configured like this:

```
<!-- Create rabbitMQ connection factory -->
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory"
        cache-mode="${rabbitmq.cacheMode}" channel-cache-size="${rabbitmq.channelCacheSize}"
        host="${rabbitmq.host}" username="${rabbitmq.username}" password="${rabbitmq.password}"
        port="${rabbitmq.port}" />

    <bean id="amqpTemplate" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate"
        scope="prototype">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="rabbitConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="channelTransacted" value="true" />
        <property name="exchange" value="wfExchange" />
        <property name="routingKey" value="abcd" />
    </bean>
```

Configuration values are read from a properties file. 
And a listener configured like this:

```
    <!-- Enable Annotation Driven Configuration -->
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory"
        cache-mode="${rabbitmq.cacheMode}" channel-cache-size="${rabbitmq.channelCacheSize}"
        host="${rabbitmq.host}" username="${rabbitmq.username}" password="${rabbitmq.password}"
        port="${rabbitmq.port}" />

    <!-- this bean looks for beans of type Queue, Exchange and Binding and declares 
        them to the broker -->
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
        auto-startup="true" />

    <!-- define event queue -->
    <rabbit:queue name="abcd" auto-delete="false"
        durable="true" exclusive="false" auto-declare="true">
    </rabbit:queue>

    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="wfExchange"
        durable="true" auto-delete="false">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="abcd" key="abcd" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>

    <!-- Instantiate event listener and listener container -->
    <bean id="eventListener" class="com.sample.Listener" />

    <rabbit:listener-container id="eventListenerContainer"
        connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" prefetch="10" acknowledge="manual">
        <rabbit:listener ref="eventListener" queue-names="abcd" />

    </rabbit:listener-container>

</beans>
```

In the application context config, I am loading:

```
<import resource="classpath:spring/sender.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:spring/listener.xml" />
```

Once I run my app which is sending 10 messages in a loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            String messageBody = "Hello number: " + (i+1);

            Message message1 = MessageBuilder
                    .withBody(messageBody.getBytes())
                    .build();

            System.out.println("Message before send: "+messageBody+ " at "+ new Date().getTime());
            entryPoint.user1.getRabbitTemplate().send(message1);
            System.out.println("Message sent: "+messageBody+ " at "+ new Date().getTime());
        }
```

And my listener code is:

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Received the message: " + new String(message.getBody()) + " at " + 
                                    new Date().getTime());
        messageList.add(message);

        channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);
    }
```

Note: 
1. RabbitTemplate has been configured to: 
        this.rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey("abcd");
        this.rabbitTemplate.setExchange("wfExchange");

2. RabbitMQ installation version - 3.5.4
3. rabbitmq.cacheMode=CHANNEL
   rabbitmq.channelCacheSize=10

My observation after multiple runs are:
send() returns after 20-40 milliseconds, even after the message has been received at the listener. Why would send take so much time to return? It is slowing down my application. Is there something else that the send() does? How do I reduce the overhead of send()?

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen it take 40ms, but transactions are notoriously slow with RabbitMQ. Disabling transactions on sends and using publisher confirms/returns is much, much faster.